# PHP Verify already running script on WIndows

Tags: php, windows

I am creating a script that will run every hour using Windows Task Scheduler.
But I don't want the script to launch if it's already running.
Is it possible to do this with Windows Task Scheduler?
If not, how can I verify it's running ?

While running, the process name is `php.exe` and the PID of the process is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. You can easily set it up in GUI. Just choose action Create task and see Settings tab (at the bottom). It is called **If the task is already running, then the following rule applies**. But default value is what do you need - **Do not start a new instance**.